# sshfs and emacs on OS X; file has changed since last visited or saved

Tags: macos, emacs, sshfs, macfuse

I am trying to use sshfs (2.2.0) and macfuse (2.0.3) along with emacs (23.2.1).

Many times when I try to save a file that I am editing from the remote file system I get the error:

```
file.txt has changed since last visited or saved; save anyway?
```

Occasionally I then get the error:

```
file.txt is write-protected; save anyway?
```

Are there any options I can use when mounting the file system that would make this work without the errors?  I have tried turning caching off (-o cache=N) which made the error show up every time I tried to save a file.

Comment: Is this a new phenomenon? What's the OS on the remote machine? Are there any cron jobs running on the remote machine which would alter the file or its permissions?